# Returning a static Class in PHP

Tags: php, static-classes

I am working on a backend project. I need to return a static object withing another static object:

```
Class this_is_a_very_long_class_name
{
    public static function call()
    {
        return self;
    }

    public static function script_link($link)
    {
        //doing stuff here...
    }
}

Class Main
{
    public static function view()
    {
        // trying to return View object
        return this_is_a_very_long_class_name::call();
    }
}
```

and I am trying to use it like this:

```
Main::view()::script_link('Some script');
```

So how can I accomplish that?

P.S.: I am not looking for another solution. I am looking for a answer what I asked.

Comment: Why?... Why not just use the right static class?  `View::script_link('Some script');`  It sounds like you're just going to create unnecessary dependencies..

Comment: Static object is an oxymoron. Static methods and attributes have nothing to do with objects or OOP.

Comment: PS: You are probably overusing static classes. You probably should just use normal classes instead, otherwise all your code will have hard coupling.

Comment: +1 all of you... this is the case when OOP makes more problem than it solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that.

Use

```
View::script_link();
```

Also this is wrong and misleading `view()->script_link` because script_link is static

### Addendum

If you your problem is your class name length I suggest you to create simple wrapper for this.

```
function createLink($string){
 return VERY_LONG_CLASS_NAME_HELLO_PHP_NAMESPACE::script_link($string);
}
```

this way you just need to `createLink();`

Comment: yea I know but I have lots of classes with very long names. I want to reach them like this.

Answer (score 0):

in php 5.3: `return new View();` (instead of `return View::self;`).
Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#example-159

Comment: this is creating a new instance. I do not want to create an instance. just want to reach static object.

Comment: You can't return `View::self`. If you want to return reference to object, you have to create instance. By the way, all what are you doing there is very bad code. Read this: http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/

Answer (score 0):

in php 5.2 use `ReflectionClass`

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax on the call is wrong.  Since it is static, what you are *trying* to do would look something like this:

```
Main::view()::script_link('Some script');
```

Except that would give you a syntax error.  Also, since it is static, you don't need to return anything.  You should make it two separate calls:

```
Main::view();
View::script_link("Some script");
```

It makes no sense to say "I need to return a static object".  If the class is defined, then the static object is present and can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a variable to hold the class, as a direct call is invalid syntax
Sample:

```
Class Main
{
    public static function view($type)
    {
        // return some class
        switch ($type) {
            case "View 2": 
                return View2;
                break;
            default:
                return View;
        }
    }
}

$v = Main::view("normal view");
$v::script_link('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for functionality as late static binding? Which is supported from PHP 5.3. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: How does this answer the question?